# Naming Convention for War File

Tags: java, war

Is there any accepted convention for naming war files?

Jar files seem to follow all lowercase with hyphens.  E.g. `my-library.jar`.  I've seen both this and camel case for wars. E.g. `my-webapp.war` or `MyWebApp.war`.

Just wondering if one is more accepted than the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. I've seen both. When using maven it is customary to use the same convention as jars, but there's nothing accepted.

Since, by default, the jar name affects the context path, you might take that into account (or use `META-INF/context.xml` to specify the context path)

Btw, usually, you deploy an application (in production) as ROOT.war

Comment: Hmm, I've never used the ROOT.war convention before. A quick search and it appears to be a Tomcat convention. Is that correct? We use Glassfish.

Answer (score 2):

Either is fine, there is no right answer, just be aware that it *can* be visible on your URL in some deployment situations, e.g.

http://www.myserver.com/MyWebApp/page.jsp

http://www.myserver.com/my-web-app/page.jsp

Some folks care more than others how this looks, and depending on your deployment it may not even be an issue, but take care to plan for it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/namingconventions-139351.html) it should be all lower case